# how do I select the first-child when it's wrapped in an anchor

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an HTML file that boils down to

```
<div class="grid">
  <a> <div class="logoContainer"> <img> <p> </p> </div> </a>
  <a> <div class="logoContainer"> <img> <p> </p> </div> </a>
  <a> <div class="logoContainer"> <img> <p> </p> </div> </a>
  <!--which is the same as-->
  <a> 
     <div class="logoContainer"> 
        <img> 
        <p> 
        </p> 
     </div> 
  </a>
</div>
```

I need to select the first .logoContainer, but because they are all children of the anchor wrapped around them, I can't use :first-child.

Is it possible to select only the first .logoContainer from .grid?

Comment: `.grid > a:first-child > .logoContainer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kMKU8/)**</kbd>

```
.grid a:first-child .logoContainer {
    color: green;
}
```

or you can also do

```
.grid a:nth-child(1) .logoContainer {
    color: green;
}
```

[Read this for more information on child and siblings selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

`.grid a:first-child .logoContainer { ... }`

This means select the `logoContainer` inside the first `a` of `.grid`. I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

you test

```
 .grid > a:first-child > div > img{border:1px solid red;}
```

Comment: `.logoContainer` is a div, not an img.